# Como instalar Spring Tool Suite no Linux?

Tags: spring-tools-suite

Galera vocês sabem uma maneira de instar o sts de um jeito de criar um atalho no linux? Toda vez que quero iniciar o mesmo tenho que ir na pasta dele e executá-lo. Já tentei em sites gringos e não deu certo pra mim.